# Does Not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My xaml.cs page is not picking up the "x:name" of my button in the Mainpage.xaml class, has anyone any idea why I'm getting this error? I am new to Xamarin and don't really know what I'm doing, I will post the code below. 
Thanks a million for any help!!!!!

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoPlayer"
             xmlns:forms="clr-            
             namespace:Plugin.MediaManager.
             Forms;assembly=Plugin.MediaManager.Forms"
             x:Class="VideoPlayer.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <forms:VideoView WidthRequest="360"
                         HeightRequest="202"
                     />
        <Button x:Name ="PlayStop"
                Text="Play"
                Clicked= "Button_Clicked">



        </Button>




    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>

xaml.cs:
using Plugin.MediaManager;
using Plugin.MediaManager.Abstractions.Enums;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace VideoPlayer
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        String videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZ-eFt5kSSQ";
        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlayStop_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PlayStop.Text == "Play")
            {
              CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(videoUrl,MediaFileType.Video);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Even if error occurs did you try to run the solution? Sometimes Xamarin shows error which are not true :P

Comment: please don't ask the same question repeatedly

Comment: It's saying that "PlayStop" doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @Jason I know it's a similar question. I couldn't find an answer last time and I need to get this done for college, Sorry. This is a Completely different class lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers